# How can you get bear spray stains off clothing?

Tags: clothing

Have bear spray stains on clothing, is there a way to get it out ?

Comment: Can you add a picture of the label, or a link to where we can see the ingredients list? The active ingredient is probably capsaicin, so I'm thinking it will be an oil-based stain, which might come out if you saturate the stain with dish soap. But it depends on the inactive ingredients as well. Also, what kind of fabric is the clothing?

Comment: VTC as necessary details lacking after a week, so we'll probably never be able to answer